# load 1.4 GB json data into mysql using ijson python

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-2.7, ijson

I came across several thread talking about ijson to load huge JSON files in python, as this is the way to not consume all memory.

My file is around 1.4 GB in size, it has several nodes (see below image), i am interested only in one node which hold most of the data (c_driver_location).

[JSON_1.4GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLdQK.png)

my goal is : i want to extract c_driver_location node data only and insert it into mysql db table (which will have four columns: id,longitude,latitude,timestamp).

table ddl:

> create table drv_locations_backup7May2017 
>   (id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key, 
>   drv_fb_id varchar(50), 
>       latitude               DECIMAL(10, 8) NOT NULL,
>       longitude              DECIMAL(11, 8) NOT NULL,
>       timestamp              int )

my problem is : i ran the first part of the attached code (till before connecting to mysql), but it is running since 20 hours and still did not finish parsing the json. (i tested on smaller file and it worked fine).

Is there an optimal way to make this faster and more efficient ?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import ijson
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql


filename = "D:\json_file.json"
drv_col_list = ['drv_fb_id','latitude','longitude','timestamp']
drv_df = DataFrame(columns = drv_col_list)
drv_df.timestamp = drv_df.timestamp.astype(int)

counter = 0
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
    parser = ijson.parse(fd)
    for prefix, event, value in parser:
        if prefix == 'c_driver_location' and str(event) == 'map_key':
            drv_fb_id = value
            counter = counter + 1
        elif prefix.endswith('.latitude'):
            latitude = value
        elif prefix.endswith('.longitude'):
            longitude = value
        elif prefix.endswith('.timestamp'):
            timestamp = value
        elif prefix.endswith(drv_fb_id) and str(event) == 'end_map':
            drv_df = drv_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'drv_fb_id':drv_fb_id,'latitude':latitude,'longitude':longitude,'timestamp':timestamp},index=[0]),ignore_index=True)
connection = pymysql.connect(host='53.000.00.00',
                             port = 3306,
                             user='user',
                             password='abcdefg',
                             db ='newdb',
                             # charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
# write to mysql 
drv_df.to_sql(con=connection, name='drv_locations_backup7May2017', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')                                               
connection.close()
```

Comment: If your code is already working and you only want to optimize it, you could post your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: If it is simply about loading huge amount of data into a mysql db, you should use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: @mpf82  thanks, i have done that now.

Comment: @AnthonyKong  i have ran the code till before connecting to mysql , just to parse the json file and put the result into a dataframe. but it is taking much time and did not finish.

Comment: Not sure why you need the data frame. Just dump the data in final format into a local file. Then run `load data` to bulk upload into the database table.

Comment: @AnthonyKong  thanks, what is the function used to dump into local file? do i do this in the code directly after the (elif prefix.endswith(drv_fb_id) and str(event) == 'end_map':)  line ?

Comment: To answer, can you provide your db table schema in the question ? (something like `create table xxx ( field1 int, ....)`  will be good enough)

Comment: @AnthonyKong        create table drv_locations_backup7May2017 
(id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key, 
drv_fb_id varchar(50), 
    latitude               DECIMAL(10, 8) NOT NULL,
 longitude              DECIMAL(11, 8) NOT NULL,
    timestamp              int )

Comment: Can you put it in the question?

Comment: @AnthonyKong  Done.

Comment: And which version of python you are using? python 2 or 3?

Comment: i use python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify your code slightly to produce a data dump.

```
import ijson


outfile = "D:\upload_data.txt"
filename = "D:\json_file.json"
drv_col_list = ['drv_fb_id','latitude','longitude','timestamp']
timestamp = drv_df.timestamp.astype(int)


ofile = open(outfile, "rw")

counter = drv_fb_id = latitude = longitude = 0
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
    parser = ijson.parse(fd)
    for prefix, event, value in parser:
        if prefix == 'c_driver_location' and str(event) == 'map_key':
            drv_fb_id = value
            counter = counter + 1
        elif prefix.endswith('.latitude'):
            latitude = value
        elif prefix.endswith('.longitude'):
            longitude = value
        elif prefix.endswith('.timestamp'):
            timestamp = value
        elif prefix.endswith(drv_fb_id) and str(event) == 'end_map':
            print >>ofile, ",".join(map(str, [drv_fb_id, latitude, longitude, timestamp]))           

close(ofile)
```

Now you have a comma delimited output in D:\upload_data.txt

The code is untested.

I do not have a test mysql database at the moment. I trust that the [mysql manual is easy to follow](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) . You table structure is not really complicated.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it and feedback accordingly.

Comment: i ran the code, the first error is " latitude is not defined". so i initialized it to latitude = '0' .  also for logitude and timestamp.    when i ran the code again i got this error :  "TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, Decimal found" .  this is on the statement of print>>ofile.

Comment: `",".join ` expects  a list of string. I updated the answer